# I want to know why can't I read the sound font file in iOS

Tags: ios, jsf-2

code is:

```
NSString *presetURLPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FluidR3_GM" ofType:@"SF2"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@",presetURLPath);
```

the `.sf2` file is exits in my project ,but output is:   `Path: null.`

What is reason ?? can anyone explain !!!

Comment: This question sums up to this: `I did something with something, and it did not work. Why?` Please explain next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *resources = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSURL *audioPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",resources,@"FluidR3_GM.SF2"]];
```

You need to pass `NSURL`

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you wrote both name and extension correctly, including capitalisation - paths on device are case-sensitive.
2. Check that this file is added to "copy resources" build phase.

Comment: the two point you said I have checked,it is no promblem.and then I find that any else file is no problem except .sf2 files.